# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so'

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu

Hi i recently installed SQL Server on my machine. It has Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS.

I followed [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/) to install server extensions for PHP 7.2 and now I'm getting these PHP warnings:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so'(tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/sqlsrv.so.so (tried:/usr/lib/php/20170718/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: That guide is for `php7.0` not `php7.2`. Unless I recall incorrectly though, neither of those come with those libraries by default. i suspect that the error is telling you the problem; thus files don't exist.

Comment: thanks @Larnu i have php 7.2 installed. it was installing drivers into another folder which is not of php 7.2

Comment: when i move those .so extension files from installed folder from php 7.2 folder it give me error so i think its not available yet for php 7.2

Comment: @Larnu i have this file pdo_sqlsrv.so into my folder /usr/lib/php/20170718 and im still getting this error PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be useful for you wight now, but this was useful for me when I was trying to install sqlsrv dricer for php in my CentOS 8

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
exit
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install php-pear
sudo yum install php-devel
#IF_ERROR:
    sudo yum install dnf-plugins-core
    sudo yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
    sudo yum install php-devel
#END_IF_ERROR
sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo echo "extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php.d/pdo.ini
sudo echo "extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php.d/pdo.ini
```

Following this steps I execute `php -m` and I haver sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv installed using php 7.2.